# String match and check in jsp with webservice data in json format

Tags: java, regex, json, jsp

in my jsp application, i have called a web service from which i am getting data in json fromat as like below

code for getting json data is

```
 String recv ="";
 String recvbuff ="";
 URL jsonpage = new URL("http://107.109.6.236:3000/api/tokens.json");
 URLConnection urlcon = jsonpage.openConnection();
 BufferedReader buffread = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlcon.getInputStream()));

 while ((recv = buffread.readLine()) != null)
 recvbuff += recv;
 buffread.close();
```

below is the recvbuff output.

```
[{"id":1,"session_id":"11611fba0cd57f2f0e62acf746d7f60b","link":"","created_at":"2013- 12-10T13:13:31.000Z","updated_at":"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z"}, 
{"id":2,"session_id":"848960680b00502fc3e4c9cf0652a5fe","link":"","created_at":"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z","updated_at":"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z"},
{"id":3,"session_id":"101155b2c4cef0034804ed9b6806422e","link":"","created_at":"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z","updated_at":"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z"},
{"id":4,"session_id":"ec1373a7bdd291f60266ab6f8445c23b","link":"","created_at":"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z","updated_at":"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z"},
{"id":5,"session_id":"3eb8b185f0cbd71ff004b30453c90f54","link":"","created_at":"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z","updated_at":"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z"}]
```

And i have a **token_id** like `3eb8b185f0cbd71ff004b30453c90f54` which will match with one of the **session_id**. If dont match with exact string it will redirect to error page.

For this i am using the following code.

```
if(recvbuff.contains(token_id)){
 out.println("<br>Hello <b>"+token_id+"</b>! done"); 
 }else{
  response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
}
```

How to get the exact match in jsp pages?

Comment: Is `recvbuff` a string containing the JSON string? Or is it a JSON Object having parsed the JSON? It's not clear how a comparison should be made on the object `recvbuff` as we don't know what that object is!

Comment: @DanTemple recvbuff is a string containing JSON string

Comment: Maybe adding the code of how `recvbuff` is made would help.
It sounds like it could be either a string with all objects in the JSON array, or it could be a string containing a single json object from the array. In the first case, you'll always match if the token_id is in the array anywhere. In the second case, you'll need to loop over the array and check each string individually.

Comment: @DanTemple `recvbuff` code is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this(Write in scriplets as its a jsp page):

```
  String ar = "[{\"id\":1,\"session_id\":\"11611fba0cd57f2f0e62acf746d7f60b\",\"link\":\"\",\"created_at\":\"2013- 12-10T13:13:31.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z\"}, \n"
                + "{\"id\":2,\"session_id\":\"848960680b00502fc3e4c9cf0652a5fe\",\"link\":\"\",\"created_at\":\"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z\"},\n"
                + "{\"id\":3,\"session_id\":\"101155b2c4cef0034804ed9b6806422e\",\"link\":\"\",\"created_at\":\"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z\"},\n"
                + "{\"id\":4,\"session_id\":\"ec1373a7bdd291f60266ab6f8445c23b\",\"link\":\"\",\"created_at\":\"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z\"},\n"
                + "{\"id\":5,\"session_id\":\"3eb8b185f0cbd71ff004b30453c90f54\",\"link\":\"\",\"created_at\":\"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2013-12-10T13:13:31.000Z\"}]";

        String token_id = "3eb8b185f0cbd71ff004b30453c90f54";
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(ar);
        boolean match_found = false;
        o:
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            if (token_id.equals(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("session_id"))) {
                match_found = true;
                break o;
            }
        }
        if(match_found  == true)
        {
            response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
        }
```

Comment: how i will create String ar ? can u help regarding this? i have very basic knowledge in java, thanks in advance

Comment: "ar" is the string containing the json string, in your case its recvbuff i think, use that.

Comment: its showing this error `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: `

Comment: i have update my question with how i am getting `recvbuff` data

Comment: that wont be helpful, because we cant access that data , are you getting the json string in recvbuff

Comment: error occured `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(recvbuff);` in this line